# Schema-validation: missing table with jpa multi level inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa, multiple-inheritance

I need to have 3 level inheritance with JPA (but just one datatable CELLAR_PER)
Here are my Entities

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PersistEntity implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer id;

     ...
}
```

The second level

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PersistEntityPer extends PersistEntity {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   @Column(
      name = "PERIOD_START",
      nullable = false)
   private Date periodStart;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   @Column(
      name = "PERIOD_END",
      nullable = false)
   private Date periodEnd;
 }
```

And the last level

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.CELLAR_PER")
public class CellarPer extends PersistEntityPer {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(
      name = "CELLAR_CASE_ID",
      nullable = false)
   private CellarCase cellarCase;
}
```

My problem is that I get this error when running my tomcat server:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [dbo.CELLAR_PER]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Please, could you help me to fix that error?

Comment: The idea with SINGLE_TABLE is that the root class defines the table, and the subclasses are persisted into it (also you define inheritance in the ROOT class ONLY). You seem to want to define the table in a subclass, which won't work. Why not look at WHAT TABLES your JPA provider has created? aka debugging

Comment: JPA created the following table, which corresponding of what I want => `code` create table dbo.CELLAR_PER (
        ID int identity not null,
        VERSION int not null,
        PERIOD_START date not null,
        PERIOD_END date not null,
        CELLAR_CASE_ID int not null,
        primary key (ID)
    ); `code`

Comment: is that dbo is schema name or table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are right. Here is the solution:

In my entity declaration, I had this:

```
@Table(name = "dbo.CELLAR_PER")
```

And I just removed the `dbo.` from the declaration. The solution is:

```
@Table(name = "CELLAR_PER")
```

Answer (score -2):

Right, I lost time just because of the "dbo." That was just that... Thanks for your help

Comment: It’s fine to answer your own question, but if you provide an answer provide an actual answer (that explains what the problem was and how to fix it). What you posted is a comment.